# Based on radio buttons, how can I list the stars in an html document according to the radio value?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to do the following:
Each time you choose a radio button, these must become in stars. Each number must be the same number of stars.

I've only been able to make the first row works; as the picture shows.

I'm not using jquery. Only vanilla javascript (pure javascript )

```js
const radio = document.getElementsByName("gender");
const boton = document.getElementById("btnBoton");
const listado = document.getElementById('contenedor-filas');

boton.addEventListener('click', enviaNumeros);

function enviaNumeros()
{
    radio.forEach(function(elementos){
        if(elementos.checked)
        {
            estrellas = document.createElement('h3');
            estrellas.textContent = elementos.value;
            listado.appendChild(estrellas);
            console.log(elementos.value)
        }
    });

    ponerEstrellas();
}


function ponerEstrellas()
{
    let c = document.getElementsByTagName('h3');
    
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
        if (c[i].textContent === '5'){
            document.querySelector('h3').innerText = "*****";
        }
    }   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Review System</title>
    <!-- style sheet -->
    <!-- Font Awesome Icon Library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>


<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="5" id="radio5"> 5<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="4" id="radio4"> 4<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="3" id="radio3"> 3<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="2" id="radio2"> 2<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="1" id="radio1"> 1<br>
            <input type="submit" value="enviar" id="btnBoton">
        </div>
    </div>

    <section class="lista-comentarios">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="contenedor-filas">
            <h1>Comment List</h1>
        </div>
    </section>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="pruebas.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I appreciate your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be adding rows with the number value of the radio button as text, and then converting every row from numbers to '*'. Why not just convert to '*' before adding rows? You only need one function then.

```js
const radio = document.getElementsByName("gender");
const boton = document.getElementById("btnBoton");
const listado = document.getElementById('contenedor-filas');

boton.addEventListener('click', enviaNumeros);

function enviaNumeros()
{
    radio.forEach(function(elementos){
        if(elementos.checked)
        {
            estrellas = document.createElement('h3');
            let s = '';
            for (let i = 0; i < elementos.value; i++) {
             s += '*';
            }
            
            estrellas.textContent = s;
            listado.appendChild(estrellas);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="5" id="radio5"> 5<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="4" id="radio4"> 4<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="3" id="radio3"> 3<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="2" id="radio2"> 2<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="1" id="radio1"> 1<br>
            <input type="submit" value="enviar" id="btnBoton">
        </div>
    </div>

    <section class="lista-comentarios">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="contenedor-filas">
            <h1>Comment List</h1>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Thank you Julian, your contribution helped me alot. Works very well.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector` will only select the first h3 element in the document.